# Prove the inverse of $H_\text{cl} =2(L_0+\bar L_0-2)/\alpha'$ is $$\Delta=\frac{\alpha'}{2} \int_0^1 d\rho \rho^{L_0+\bar L_0 -3}$$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, string-theory, propagator

Quote Clifford Johnson $D$-brane page 153

> $\Delta$ is the closed string propagator... the inverse of $H_\text{cl} =2(L_0+\bar L_0-2)/\alpha'$, the closed string Hamiltonian, which we can easily represent as:
> $$\Delta=\frac{\alpha'}{2} \int_0^1 d\rho \rho^{L_0+\bar L_0 -3}$$
> and we must integrate over the modulus $l=-\log \rho$ of the cylinder from $0$ to $\infty$.

Could you show a bit of how the inverse operation was done from $H_\text{cl}$ to $\Delta$, please? Also, the "modulus" $l$ was unmentioned from the text and the following expressions, so what did "integrate over the modulus $l$" mean?

Comment: Basically you use $\int_0^1 dx x^{a-1} = \frac{1}{a}$

Comment: @Prahar Ah! I see. Thank you. But is there a particular reason to put it in front of $\rho\in(0,1)$ instead of $\exp()$? It confused me when I was thinking about $0.01^{L_0-\bar L_0}$.

Comment: Just deprecated notation, I guess

Comment: Footnotes: So the module space $l$(what does it mean?)  $\int_0^\infty dl [\text{Jacobian}] \exp(-l( L_0+ \bar L_0-3) )=\int_0^1 d\rho \rho^{L_0+\bar L_0-3}$

Comment: Your $\ell$ denotes the Schwinger time (or the string theory version thereof).